# OpenLayers 2 error 404 tile not found

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers-2, tiles, xyz

I have a BBOX area of my county. I serving the OSM tiles (Apache 2) from a local disk using openlayers 2 XYZ scheme. How can I prevent loading non-existent files out of my BBOX area? I have 8 zoom levels with around 400k tiles.

I managed to "disable" the visibility of non-existent and pink tiles with a CSS trick but I can't prevent the browser reading these files.

I always got these errors in browsers console (there are hundreds of them):

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

OL2:

```
new OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ("OSM Offline",
  ["http://localhost/csongradm/${z}/${x}/${y}.png"],
    {
      numZoomLevels: 18,
      visibility: true,
      sphericalMercator: true,
      isBaseLayer: true,
      buffer: 3
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Use restrict extent as below example, so User will not go beyond the defined extent.
**Reference:**   http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.restrictedExtent

**Example:**
http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/restricted-extent.html